# how to use share memory with Golang?

Tags: go, ipc

How does golang share or read other processes shared memory?
I've checked some information, but did not find relevant information. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for memory mapped files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the world of go, don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating. If you really want to have a try, you can call the C API with cgo:

**wrapper.c:**

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int my_shm_open(char* filename, int open_flag){
    int shm_id;
    key_t key;
    key = ftok(filename, 0x03);
    if(key == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    if(open_flag)
        shm_id = shmget(key, 4096, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600);
    else
        shm_id = shmget(key, 0, 0);
    if(shm_id == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    return shm_id;
}

int my_shm_update(int shm_id, char* content){
    char* addr;
    addr = (char*)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if(addr == (char*)-1){
        return -1;
    }
    if(strlen(content) > 4095)
        return -1;
    strcpy(addr, content);
    shmdt(addr);
    return 0;
}

int my_shm_close(int shm_id){
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}

char* my_shm_read(char* filename){
    int shm_id;
    char* addr;
    char* s;
    shm_id = my_shm_open(filename, 0);
    if(shm_id == -1)
        return NULL;
    addr = (char*)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if(addr == (char*)-1){
        return NULL;
    }
    s = (char*)malloc(strlen(addr) + 1);
    strcpy(s, addr);
    shmdt(addr);
    return s;
}
```

**reader.go**

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "wrapper.c"
import "C"
import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func read(filename string) string {
    f := C.CString(filename)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(f))
    s := C.my_shm_read(f)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
    return C.GoString(s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(read("/tmp"))
}
```

**writter.go:**

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "wrapper.c"
import "C"
import "unsafe"

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type errorString struct {
    s string
}

func (e *errorString) Error() string {
    return e.s
}

func open(file string) (int, error) {
    f := C.CString(file)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(f))
    r := int(C.my_shm_open(f, C.int(1)))
    if r == -1 {
        return 0, &errorString{"error"}
    }
    return r, nil
}

func update(shm_id int, content string) error {
    c := C.CString(content)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c))
    r := int(C.my_shm_update(C.int(shm_id), c))
    if r == -1 {
        return &errorString{"update error"}
    }
    return nil
}

func close(shm_id int) error {
    C.my_shm_close(C.int(shm_id))
    return nil
}

func main() {
    id, err := open("/tmp")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer close(id)
    err = update(id, "hello world")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(1e9 * 100)
}
```

run the writer, then the reader by `go run filename`.
The code is from [here](https://gist.github.com/jedy/3282764)

Answer (score -7):

golang: It is a programming language, so it does not relate to the shared memory that the operating system level things. Not to say golang not use shared memory, but this is not it need to be defined. Posix use shared memory, you can use syscall package, which contains a lot of system calls, as long as the reference c system call interface on the line.